# Node.js: serve static resources issue on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

On OpenShift I created basic node0.10 cartridge and have node_modules folder from which I am trying to get certain files in my `index.html` but it just gives me `404` http errors.

`index.html` imports look the following way:

```
<script src="es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

<script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Then I have `server.js` where I am requiring `app.js`:

```
...
var app = express();
require('./app.js').setApp(app);
...
```

`app.js` looks like this:

```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var path = require("path");

   exports.setApp = function (app) {

      app.use(express.compress());

      var oneDay = 86400000;
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/node_modules'), {   maxAge: oneDay }));
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/'), { maxAge: oneDay }));

   };
```

What could be the issue? Why OpenShift can not access static files in `node_modules` folder and its subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, server cannot read the files through static folders that you pointed in the html until you app.use() them.
Add one line in your server.js
Inside the  `self.initializeServer = function() {}`

```
self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

According to code above, change the html to

```
<script src="/public/js..."></script>
```

The same thing is

```
self.app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
```

Will need to change the path to:

```
<script src="/js..."></script>
```

Read [this article](http://rtwc-simone.rhcloud.com/docs/server.html) for more information about server.js